# Transforming/GroupingBy values inside List

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, groupingby

**Given**
`List<Student>` where each `Student` has `List<Book>`, group by `Book` for `List<Student>`

**Working Solution (Uses Java 9)**
I already have a working code mentioned below

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> studs = createStudents();

        var data = studs.stream()
                .flatMap(s -> s.getBooks()
                        .stream()
                        .map(b -> Pair.of(b, s))) // <------ is possible without using external class?
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        p -> p.getBook(),
                        Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getStud().getFirstName(), Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println("All books: " + data);
    }

    private static List<Student> createStudents() {
        Book javaCompleteReference = new Book("Java Complete Reference");
        Book ocjp = new Book("Java OCJP");
        Book sql = new Book("SQL");
        Book spring = new Book("SPRING in Action");

        return List.of(
                new Student(1, "A", List.of(javaCompleteReference, spring)),
                new Student(2, "B", List.of(spring, sql, ocjp)),
                new Student(3, "C", List.of(javaCompleteReference, sql))
        );
    }
}
```

**Looking for:**

1. I have used flatMap and an intermediate class Pair. Is it possible to achieve the final result without using intermediate transformation using Pair class

Code Base:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String id;
    private Integer pages;

    public Book(String title, String id, Integer pages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public Book(String title) { this.title = title; }

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public String getId() { return id; }

    public Integer getPages() { return pages; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return title; }
}

class Pair {
    Book book;
    Student stud;

    private Pair(Book book, Student stud) {
        this.book = book;
        this.stud = stud;
    }

    static Pair of(Book book, Student stud) { return new Pair(book, stud); }

    public Book getBook() { return book; }

    public Student getStud() { return stud; }
}

public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private List<Book> books;

    public Student(Integer id, String firstName, List<Book> books) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.books = books;
    }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }

    public List<Book> getBooks() { return books; }
}
```

Output: `All books: {Java Complete Reference=[A, C], SQL=[B, C], SPRING in Action=[A, B], Java OCJP=[B]}`

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*is the solution attempted elegant*" - Opinion-based. --- "*there is better way to achieve the result.*" - What is your metric for *better*? This question in unclear.

Comment: Ok. Reduced the problem statement to one question

Comment: I do not think that it is possible since we can read every `Student` only once, hence we have to create some temporary ressource (the `Pair` instances) for re-read. Why do you think that a solution without a `map`-step is "*better*"? Or rather: what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think two nested `forEach` is more readable. nevertheless you can do like this too. `studs.stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, s) -> s.getBooks().forEach(b ->
                                          m.merge(b, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(s.getFirstName())),
                                                (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2);return l1; })),
                        HashMap::putAll);`

Comment: @Turing85 It felt like unwanted route to me, was looking for alternative approach. The problem to solve is achieve the transformed result but flatMap block looks little uneasy to me.

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks for alternative. but that looks more jumbled to be, wouldn't want to perform a war while doing terminal operation

Comment: @Ajeetkumar: Have you found your solution?

Comment: discussions added value to my knowledge, however I think my existing implementation is more clear than other clever suggestions.

Comment: I think so. Your current solution is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** possible using the Stream API as long as you need to keep **both** information about the Student's name **and** each Book in the context in order to form an output map. Flatmapping into a single element (pair) is the only wat to go.

A proof and an alternative (I guess not better) solution is using a combination of `Collectors.flatMapping` and `Collectors.toMap` where you define all the `keyMapper`, `valueMapper` and `mergeFunction`. You can clearly see as in the `Collectors.grouping`, you need the combination of all the Student's names **and** each Book relationship for each one.

```
var data = studs.stream().collect(Collectors.flatMapping(
    student -> student.getBooks()
                      .stream()
                      .map(book -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                              student.getFirstName(), book)),
    Collectors.toMap(
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
        entry -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(entry.getKey())),
        (leftList, rightList) -> { leftList.addAll(rightList); return leftList; })));
```

Answer (score 0):

> is possible without using external class?

Yes, it is possible even in earlier versions of java. Just use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>` instead:

```
.map(b -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(b, s)))
```

Then you can access the values by calling `getKey()` and `getValue()`.

Comment: How is this different from using a `Pair`? Can we actually construct a `Map` with a collector, resusing the `SimpleEntry`s?

Comment: @Turing85 "How is this different... ?". Well, at least you don't have to define another class. Regarding the reusing SimpleEntry's, not sure. Perhaps we can.